# Asset was not declared to be precompiled in production (Rails 5.0.0.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I am new to `Rails 5.0.0.1`

I followed the guidelines in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#controller-specific-assets:

> You can also opt to include controller specific stylesheets and JavaScript files only in their respective controllers using the following:
>
> `<%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] %>` or `<%= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller] %>`
>
> When doing this, ensure you are not using the require_tree directive, as that will result in your assets being included more than once.

I generated some scaffolds (which also generated the assets -- `.coffee` and `.scss`)

When I do `rails s` and access one of the scaffold's main page, it generated an error:

> Asset was not declared to be precompiled in production.
>
> Add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( myscaffold.css )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server

---

I do as it said, and it worked, but is there **any other way to simplify this process**?

I wish that I can generate some other scaffolds or controllers with their assets without doing any more concern of adding new lines inside the `config/initializers/assets.rb`.

I will receive any other alternatives too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you just try this..

check your `Gemfile`  `gem 'sprockets-rails', '2.3.3'`

And `bundle install`

Comment: And it's working @karthick.
I used version `3.2.0`.

May I ask why it should be version `2.3.3`?
And thanks a lot

Comment: i used that version on my last project..you update can also put version.that's not a problem..

Comment: That did it. How the spambiscuit would someone supposed to be productive without using on the fly compile for dynamic asset links, I don't know...

Comment: What I think happened here is, that the newer sprocket-rails gem added the error message "Asset was not declared to be precompiled in production." to warn developers of an error that otherwise would happen in production.

In most development workflows you won't run into this issue very often, as  with sprockets / asset pipeline you tend to compile all styles / javascripts into one (or few) files.

Comment: I recommend `bundle update` instead of `bundle install`.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate files

```
config/initializers/assets.rb
```

Then add

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( your_file_name.scss )
```

Restart server

Comment: this didnt solve the issue for me